# javafx tableview row text color is not changed using pseudo class

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-css

I need to show only a few rows with red text in a tableview, but no result!

My code:

```
PseudoClass pClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("warn");
myTable.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<MyData>, TableRow<MyData>>() {

                    @Override
                    public TableRow<MyData> call(TableView<MyData> param) {
                        return new TableRow<MyData>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void updateItem(MyData item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (item == null || empty) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                setItem(item);
                                pseudoClassStateChanged(pClass, item.getWarning());
                            }
                        };
                    }
                });
```

The css

```
.table-view .table-row-cell .text{
    -fx-fill: black; 
}

.table-view .table-row-cell .text:warn{
    -fx-fill: red; 
}
```

Can anyone review it or suggest some easier way?

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the pseudo class on the `TableRow`, not on the `.text` nodes. Therefore the pseudoclass selector needs to be combined with the selector selecting the `TableRow`, not with the selector selecting the text element:

```css
.table-view .table-row-cell:warn .text {
```